# What is the ideal age to get a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, career-path

There have been a few "how old is too old to get a PhD" questions, and I don't intend this to be a duplicate--they were more focused on age from an actual admissions standpoint.

While I'm interested in general to hear people's thoughts on the question I posed, I'll also give my own current situation, in case anyone has thoughts here:

I'm currently 25, 2.5 years out of undergrad. I got my MS degree directly after undergrad, which took 1 calendar year/3 semesters. So I've been at my current job at a research org for 1.5 years now. My current plan is to apply for my PhD at 27, so I'd be starting at 28. I think this is the ideal amount of time to improve both my skills and my CV, but isn't too long that I will be middle-aged when I finish and have a more difficult life adjustment as a PhD student, and have less time in my post-PhD career. If it makes a difference, I'm in the social sciences/public policy field.

Thoughts? Am I dumb to wait until my late 20s? Should people all be waiting until they're 30 because they're too young and unexperienced out of undergrad? Is it undergrad-PhD straight through or bust?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as opinion-based; it isn't really possible to answer a question like this without a substantial influence of a opinion, and it's been decided that such questions not be supported in the stack exchange format.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Are current top questions such as "How can a TA help a student who is certain she sucks at programming?", "My student's family won't let her study what she wants", "Upset by fellow students' comments on my attractiveness; how to react?", and "Cheated on an exam when I was eight years old. Should I tell graduate admissions?" able to be answered without a substantial influence of opinion?

Comment: My advice would be the younger the better. Think also that you'd probably want to start a family at some point (if not yet), and PhD scholarship might be not the time to have kids due to all the stress.

Comment: I don't make the rules @Blaise, you can take it up in Meta. Like many of the SE close reasons, "opinion-based" has a little different meaning here than on its face. You might be able to improve your question if you instead asked for "negatives about postponing a PhD" - but it seems like you already know those negatives so you aren't asking about that. All you are asking is for someone to weight the negatives and positives for you, which is completely opinion.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation. Would it not be possible, though, for someone to offer some research that's been done that people who finish their PhD before X age make more money? Or to get insight from someone who works in admissions that they don't consider older applicants, or from a professor who says they will only take students < 25 years of age? I think there are some objective thoughts that can be presented--both positive and negative.

Comment: 10. It is absolutely necessary to avoid puberty during your first postdoc, when the pressure is highest.

Comment: "What are the extent of financial benefits to postponing a PhD by 5 years?" would not be an opinion-based question, though it would have other problems of breadth, and it depends a lot on your current position. If your PhD is going to lead to a career as a professor (no guarantee of that) then you are going to miss out on career-pinnacle salary years and instead sit at your current pay. If you plan to work outside academia, getting your PhD anytime might not be a financially sound decision. SE doesn't really like just "make a list" questions either so it's best if you can give some direction.

Comment: Perhaps a better question (for you and this site) would be something like: _how helpful is it to have X years of work experience before applying for PhD programs in field Y?_

Comment: The ideal age to get a PhD is 3-4 years after you start one :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, frankly, no "ideal" age for starting a Ph.D. There's not even a "better" time. All that is really important is demonstrating that you have an aptitude for doing research in the proposed field of study. If you can demonstrate that at age 20, great; if you've had a change of heart at 30 or even 40, and decide you want to go back to school, that's cool, too.

However, there is an advantage in doing it sooner rather than later—adjusting back to "student" habits is easier when you're closer to finishing your undergraduate than when you're older. It's also usually easier to move around when you're younger than when you're older and might have a (larger) family to worry about.

But from the perspective of someone who reviews admissions applications, I'd say the single most important factor is demonstrating your potential to be a PhD level researcher. If you can do that, I'm not nearly as concerned about someone having a 3.4 versus a 3.6 or a 3.8 GPA, or a 155 or a 165 on the GRE.